# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type TaharatBloc

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to route my TaharatPage and I'm getting such errors

> The following assertion was thrown building TaharatGeneralPage(dirty):
> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type TaharatBloc.

```
    No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<TaharatBloc>().
```

[image: The Error]
[image: The Routing]
[image: The Coding]

[image: Where I was Routing it]

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the generated routes use named navigation instead of giving a new MaterialPageRoute